# Bootstrap Carousel Thumbnail Border not auto updating.

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When the carousel goes to the next slide the border on the thumbnails should move to the next thumbnail to correspond with that image change. They do not. I discovered this error when adding a closing div to .carousel-inner that wasnt there it was causing my carousel to collapse after the last slide. Here is the code.

HTML

```
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
              <img src="img/100325-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Regional Open Space Comparison" />
                 <div class="carousel-caption"><p></p>
                   <div class="photo-credit"><p>Photo Credit:<br />Media: Please submit high-resolution image requests to</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>                     
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
              <img lazy-src="img/100325-02.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Ecological Analysis" />
                <div class="carousel-caption"><p></p>
                  <div class="photo-credit"><p>Photo Credit: <br />Media: Please submit high-resolution image requests to</p>
                  </div>
                </div>             
             </div>
           </div>
```

CSS

```
  .carousel-selector > .active, .selected img {
   border: solid 2px #003C30;
   }
```

JS

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 13000
});

 // handles the carousel thumbnails
 $('.carousel-selector').click(function () {
  var selectorIdx = $(this).closest('li').index();

$('#myCarousel')
  .carousel(selectorIdx)
  .find('.carousel-selector').removeClass('selected')
  .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected')
  .end()
  .find('.item').removeClass('selected')
  .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('active');
 });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that all be easier by simply using index values?

Comment: Would  that solve the problem @isherwood

Comment: I'll be happy to show you that technique if you'd like to construct a demo at http://jsfiddle.net. Use images from http://lorempixel.com or http://placehold.it if yours aren't accessible.

Comment: Absolutely here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xr8qzxmg/

Comment: Also the thumbnails only get the css border on click, they should auto update with that class selected

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you'd do it by index rather than all that string parsing.

```
$('.carousel-selector').click(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').find('.carousel-selector').removeClass('selected');

    var selectorIdx = $(this).addClass('selected').closest('li').index();

    $('#myCarousel').find('.item').removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected');

    $('#myCarousel').carousel(selectorIdx);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xr8qzxmg/4)**

Note that 1) I've added classes to each control element, and 2) I've removed the previous/next controls because they were overlapping the individual controls.

Here's a fun chained version:

```
$('#myCarousel')
      .carousel(selectorIdx)
      .find('.carousel-selector').removeClass('selected')
      .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected')
      .end()
      .find('.item').removeClass('selected')
      .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('active');
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xr8qzxmg/7)**

Comment: Thanks, the first thumbnail class="carousel-selector selected" remains highlighted even though I am navigating the thumbs, also there is now an outline with my main carousel images. I'm using your second demo btw

Comment: Also would it be because I have kept the prev next controls? Those need to remain as they were part of the design I'm working on

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The clicked thumbnail is highlighted for me. I'm leaving the office now, but I'll check back later or tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: Apologies @isherwood, demo 2 works nicely, I had two closing divs in the wrong place. 

I removed the border from the large carousel images by using the following css:

.carousel-selector > .active, .selected img {}


Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Both versions do exactly the same thing. The jQuery methods are just arranged differently in each.

Comment: I think I need your help again with this. I discovered the carousel was collapsing after the last slide. The ending div for .carousel-inner was out of place. Now that I've corrected that the border (or .selected) doesnt auto update with the slides to show the user which one they are on, instead it only works on click. This is the case in your fiddles as well.

Comment: Sorry, but you'll need to ask a new question or unaccept and update this one. SO isn't a discussion forum.